# MS Excel How to Hide or Change Color of text in a cell with no value

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I created a multi-page spreadsheet file originally in LibreOffice Calc (herein after "Calc") and I am now working with it using Microsoft Excel. This is a tool I use to create a week-based report of stores I need to visit. There's a separate data entry sheet, and then four successive report sheets, each identical in layout but each one showing the next successive set of entries. This enables me to enter up to one month's worth of scheduling.

Some days, I am not visiting a particular store. On such a day, I would leave the store number cell blank on the data entry sheet. On the corresponding report entry for that day, I expect all the cells containing formulas (mostly vlookup formulas, but some just straight math formulas) to appear blank. Now, whether I'm using Calc or Excel, I expect that the default thing it will do is to show me some kind of message stating there's no valid data to display. Both show the statement "#N/A". What I want to happen is to change that text to white, so that the cell *appears* to be blank. The fact that "#N/A" is actually in there doesn't matter.

In Calc, I'm able to use Conditional Formatting to control for this, wherein I tell it if the cell's value doesn't equal anything (strictly, if it's equal to 0) then color the text white.

I can't for the life of me get this to work in Excel. For laughs, I even tried the conditional value of "#N/A" and *that **also*** didn't work. Does anyone here have an idea how I might achieve a similar result to what I get in Calc?

Comment: Is Excel showing the Error `#NA` or a string `#NA`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this question earlier. How can I tell the difference?

Comment: `=ISNA(cellRef)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ok, cool! I entered =ISNA(C6) (or the appropriate cell) in the various different fields' respective conditional formatting and it worked! Since that is a heck of a lot of cells, this is going to take me some time to retrofit, but thanks so much!

Comment: Depending on what you are really doing, you may be able to enter it as a single formula, possibly with mixed or relative addressing, and adjust the `Applies To` section appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing the error value `#NA` then use the formula `=ISNA($A1)`

Comment: I'm assuming you mean to paste that into the conditional formatting area under what the value of the cell should be to get the conditional formatting. I put it in, and it made no difference. Hmm...

Comment: Have you tried calling `=ISNA(` *``cell``* `)`  from another cell?

Comment: @mclark2145 No. It is a formula. So you would use it in the `use a formula` section.